# Button unclicked says 'see', button clicked says 'close'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a faq list that displays that way : question and button "see the answer".

When "see the answer" is clicked, it immediatly becomes "close".

My problem is I can't reverse it when "close" is clicked. It should become a "see the answer" button again.

Here is the html

```
<p class="faq-question">Question</p>
<div class="collapse js-faq-answer" id="collapseExample">
    <div class="well">
        Answer
    </div>
</div>
<a class="btn btn-primary js-faq-button" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">See the answer</a>
```

And here is my script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-faq-button').click(function(){
        if(this.click){
            $(this).addClass('js-faq-button-clicked');
            $(this).removeClass('js-faq-button');
            $('.js-faq-button-clicked').html('Close');
        }
        else{
            $(this).addClass('js-faq-button');
            $(this).removeClass('js-faq-button-clicked');
            $('.js-faq-button-clicked').html('See the answer');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition is incorrect. I'd check to see if button has the `js-faq-button-clicked` class. If not add it, if so, remove it.

This isn't the only way, but it will certainly work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-faq-button').click(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass("js-faq-button-clicked")){
            $(this).addClass('js-faq-button-clicked');
            $(this).removeClass('js-faq-button');
            $('.js-faq-button-clicked').html('Close');
        }
        else{
            $(this).addClass('js-faq-button');
            $(this).removeClass('js-faq-button-clicked');
            $('.js-faq-button-clicked').html('See the answer');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just add the js-faq-button-clicked as a class, and toggle it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.js-faq-button').on('click',function(){
        var self = $(this);
        self.toggleClass('js-faq-button-clicked');
        if(self.hasClass('js-faq-button-clicked')) {
            self.html('Close');
        }
        else {
            self.html('See the answer');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try also checking the value (i.e. the text) of your button in the if condition and not just the "Click" event. Currently you are just saying "On click, change to close". You need to let it know to toggle back and forth between the two prompts.

Answer (score -2):

Try checking its text when you click it: if it is "See the answer" it will becom "close" and viceversa

Comment: That's a bad idea, because changing the text later on will require you to change the code as well.